# Trying to add UIImage as background in storyboard (without overlapping my other ViewController elements)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, storyboard, interface-builder

I am trying to add an UIImage to my ViewController in the Interface Builder without overlapping all my content. Is there a way to do so? Whenever I place it you can kind of see through it, but I just wanted to hide it if possible (without deleting it) because it becomes bothersome to rearrange the position of the other elements (labels, buttons, views, etc). I know I can do it programmatically (which I've done so) but I just wanted to know if there was an IB alternative.

As an aside question I would like to know how does iOS handles the size of the images (resolution), because the image I am assigning as my VC background (programmatically) it's high resolution, and UIImage does not have a property .contentMode, therefore I cannot assign it as aspect fit.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: You can assign the imageView contentMode in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Drag the image view behind other views in the left panel for the view controller in IB.

Comment: And how would you do such thing?